# Why can reinterpret_cast not convert an int to int?

Tags: c++, pointers, integer, type-conversion, reinterpret-cast

My compiler is the latest VC++ 2013 RC.

```
void f()
{
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = reinterpret_cast<int>(n1); // error C2440
}
```

> error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int'

Why can reinterpret_cast not be used in such an obvious case?

Comment: sounds like a bug

Comment: interesting, the same thing in MSVC2010

Comment: this also does not compile: const int x = 10; int y = const_cast<int>(x);

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: (My compiler is the latest VC++ 2013 RC.)  What gave it away? :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[According](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) to cppreference.com the following conversion is available only since C++11:

> An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member
>   type can be converted to its own type. The resulting value is the same
>   as the value of expression.

which [may not be implemented](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/09/09/visual-studio-2013-rc-now-available.aspx) in Visual Studio 2013 RC yet.

Comment: I think you're right. `[C++03: 5.2.10/1]` clearly states that only the listed conversions are valid, and this self-conversion is not one of them. Hence, this is not a VS bug so much as a C++11 feature as-yet-unimplemented.

Answer (score 24):

The C++ standard says (5.2.10.2) (emphasis mine):

> The reinterpret_cast operator shall not cast away constness (5.2.11). **An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member type can be explicitly converted to its own type**; such a cast yields the
>   value of its operand.

So I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: Is this correct answer the accepted by shoe ...because i am testing  this example with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) and facing same issue..Please reply